# How to spin up Celery container with SQS usage

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to setup Celery to talk with AWS SQS. Celery put log as below and after that container is going down and starting up again in loop. Log as below:

trim...

```
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,715: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,798: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,799: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,801: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,801: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,806: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,806: DEBUG/MainProcess] Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,806: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting config variable for region to {'eu-west-1'}
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,808: DEBUG/MainProcess] Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,815: DEBUG/MainProcess] Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7fed0d144940>
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,899: DEBUG/MainProcess] Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/sqs/2012-11-05/service-2.json
[2020-08-05 09:32:35,902: DEBUG/MainProcess] Event creating-client-class.sqs: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fed096053a0>
[2020-08-05 09:32:36,907: DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
 
 -------------- celery@ip-10-10-12-215.eu-central-1.compute.internal v4.4.6 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.14.177-139.254.amzn2.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2020-08-05 09:32:35
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app_name:0x7fed0d6f18e0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://aws_access_key:**@localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                
[tasks]
  . app_name.tasks.check_new_users
  . app_name.tasks.send_mail_for_new_user
  . app_name.tasks.test_task
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
```

Settings in Django are as follows: (variables are taken from SSM)

```
AWS_REGION = os.getenv("AWS_REGION")
BROKER_URL = os.getenv("BROKER_URL", "amqp://app_name-rabbitmq//")
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqs'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    "region": {AWS_REGION},
    "polling_interval": 60,
    "queue_name_prefix": "prod-"
}
CELERY_BROKER_URL = BROKER_URL
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'yaml']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
RESULT_BACKEND = None

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("app_name.tasks",)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "check_new_users": {"task": "tasks.app_name.check_new_users", "schedule": crontab(hour="9,17", minute=0,)},
}
```

Does any one had situation like that and could help?
IAM role is SQS full access for time being.
EDIT: If any other detail is needed please let me know.